# Jasper Reports very slow on first call to each report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Started using Jasper Reports (version 5.6.1) and I'm getting a very long delay when calling for the first time a report (around 15 seconds). The other calls execute very fast

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:/TestReport.jasper", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

This is my test report. As you can see it's a very simple report just with a Static Text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.2.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2014-11-07T18:15:19 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="960" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c19b229f-4d8a-4c81-ae10-d9fc8c37b34a">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.75"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="160" y="24" width="100" height="30" uuid="692f5b61-7f48-42d7-b93f-a273f7c99890"/>
                <text><![CDATA[This is a test]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Any ideas what can be causing this, and how can I solve it?

If I try previewing the report on jaspersoft studio it renders it very fast too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a corrupted JBoss AS7 installation. After I reinstalled the server everything started working OK.